# Scroll free page Onsen UI

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I'm currently working on an image edit app built with cordova APIs and onsen ui . in one of my pages i have a HTML5 canvas which can probably be as large as required . the page has a toolbar and a bottom toolbar.

To add scroll functionality to the page content i tried multiple choices , default webView stroller , a jQuery plugin I used to use my project or mobile specific libraries like iScroll ..

And with all of them horizontal scrolling has a very bad behavior or not even working . and it made me think that it's because that onsen ui pages have - should be capable of scrolling vertically but not horizontally , and it's not that unusual that I'm facing this problem .

Overall for the general case of this problem, a page that can be scrolled containing only a canvas as content, what could I do ?

thanks .

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but maybe you can try with `ons-scroller` and see how it works: http://onsen.io/guide/components.html#ons-scroller